# Start a Phoenix application, got error (UndefinedFunctionError)

Tags: docker, elixir, phoenix-framework, release

Using docker to build a image to deploy, got:

```
[info] Application myapp exited: exited in: myapp.Application.start(:normal, [])
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function myapp.Application.start/2 is undefined (module myapp.Application is not available)
            myapp.Application.start(:normal, [])
            (kernel) application_master.erl:273: :application_master.start_it_old/4
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,myapp,{bad_return,{{'Elixir.myapp.Application',start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{'Elixir.myapp.Application',start,[normal,[]],[]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,\"application_master.erl\"},{line,273}]}]}}}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,myapp,{bad_return,{{'Elixir.myapp.Application',start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{'Elixir.myapp.Application',start,[norma
```

In `myapp/rel/config.exs` file:

```
...

release :orange do
  set version: current_version(:orange)
  set applications: [
    :runtime_tools
  ]
  set vm_args: "./vm.args"
end
```

In `mix.exs` file:

```
def application do
 [
   mod: {Myapp.Application, []},
   extra_applications: [:logger]
 ]
end
```

I'm using Kubernetes to deploy the application. The first time, all the pods can run successfully. After a while, the pods went:

```
Back-off restarting failed container
Error syncing pod
```

When check pod logs using `kubectl`, got errors above.
Is anything set wrong?

Comment: Please share the `MyApp.Application` module.

Comment: The error message says `myapp.Application`. You have a typo somewhere `myapp` -> `Myapp`.

Comment: I have known the reason. I lost some main data in the app. Thank you for your notice very much! -- @mudasobwa

Comment: Make sure your .dockerignore isn't excluding your `lib` directory from getting copied into the container. In my case, the app was compiling fine without any actual source code and this was the result I got.